# Ambiguous use of reloaddata() (CorePlot)

Tags: ios, swift, plot, core-plot

I want to use `plot.reloadData()` instead of `graph.reloadData()` with CorePlot but I receive a strange error (Xcode 8 beta 3) : **Ambiguous use of reloadData()**. I've tried many things :

```
(plot as CPTPlot).reloadData()
```

or

```
graph.plot(withIdentifier: "Plot").reloadData()
```

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new auto-renaming features of Swift 3 when importing Objective-C APIs is causing a name collision. Please drop a bug report on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues). I'll see what I can do to fix it.

Comment: It's fixed on the `release-2.2` branch.